# Angular - Plugin chartjs-plugin-crosshair does not work

Tags: angular, npm, chart.js

### Question

I want to use the `chartjs-plugin-crosshair` in my angular project to show  crosshair lines in 2 [linked charts](https://chartjs-plugin-crosshair.netlify.app/samples/). I've installed following packages using rpm:

- `"chart.js": "^4.1.2"`
- `"chartjs-plugin-crosshair": "^1.2.0"`

It seems that the import of the library is not done correctly and therefore it does not take the settings of the plugin. I get following errors:

- error TS2305: Module '"chartjs-plugin-crosshair"' has no exported member 'Interpolate'.
- error TS2339: Property 'interpolate' does not exist on type 'InteractionModeMap'.

You can take a look at the [StackBlitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-r3mxjd?file=app/app.component.ts). If I've made a mistake, please let me know.

### Answer

Basically to fix it you have to create a file named index.d.ts and add this:

```
declare module 'chartjs-plugin-crosshair';
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)?

Comment: https://github.com/AbelHeinsbroek/chartjs-plugin-crosshair/issues/109